# How to create multi database support software?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sqlite

I am creating a software for retail shops and I want that my software support SQL Server and SQLite. If the user is a standalone (one PC) select the sqlite database and if it is over the network then choose the SQL Server option.

I am developing this software in Visual Studio 2010 and vb.net language.

As research we have three types of connections in Visual Studio, ODBC, OleDB and MSSQL.

And OLEDB can support MS-Access database and SQL Server.

Any comment and idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: How about using an ORM like Nhibernate to abstract the database layer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to code your applications is to abstract functionality into [different tiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) or [layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture). This can mean lots of things and can get quite complex, but the general idea is to keep your application's parts separated. Let's assume you have an inventory form in your program where you can look up current inventory. The form that displays the inventory doesn't need to know what database your customer is running. Generally you're better served by it not knowing. Likewise, your code that accesses the respective database, whether it be SQL Server, SQLite, or Access, doesn't really need to know what your Inventory form is going to do with the data it is retrieving. All your Inventory code should be doing is displaying your inventory in a way that's most useful to your customer, and all your data coding should be doing is getting the data that is requested of it.

The route I would probably take in your situation is to create a data provider class. Inside that class is where you would encapsulate logic for the different database functions you may have, as well as the different database systems your customers may have. Say for instance a store owner just received a shipment of products and needs to add one to his store's inventory. Ideally, your program should simply be able to perform a call like `DataProvider.AddInventory()`. Inside the DataProvider class, you would write code to keep track of which database solution the customer is using as well as an implementation of logic for each of the database solutions you'd like to support. Ideally, you should implement every data function you may need your application to perform so that it can be called very simply like the `AddInventory()` example.

Implementations of data providers can be as simple or complex as you like. In some cases where you're going to have multiple applications written in multiple different languages on multiple different platforms accessing your data source from multiple locations, it may make sense to write some sort of middleware. In your case, it sounds like this is the type of application that will reside "in house" and should be served fine by abstracting the data access to a separate class.